# Setting up multiclass decision forest/neural network on smaller dataset

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, azure-machine-learning-service

So I have a set of data, 1900 rows and 22 columns. 21 column is just numbers but that one crucial that I want to train the data on has 3 stages: a,b, and c.

I have tried both decision trees/jungles, and neural networks and no matter how I set them up I can't get more than 55% precision.

Usually it's around 50% accuracy and the best I was ever able to get was 55% overall accuracy and around 70% average.

Should I even use NN on a such small dataset? As I said I tried with other ML algorithms but they don't yield anything better.

Comment: 1900 rows for 22 columns is not really a great dataset for NN model... But have you tried dimensionality reduction techniques like PCA first? You can do that perhaps to reduce you columns to 4 or 5... In that case you can probably find a good model...

Answer (score 1):

I think that there is no clear answer to your question. Low accuracy score may come from a few reasons. I will state some of them in the following points :

1. When you use decision trees / neural networks - low accuracy may be a result of a wrong setup of metaparameters (like maximum height of a tree or number of trees in DT or wrong topology or data preparation in NN case). What I advise you is to use a grid or random search for both NN and DT to look for the best metaparameters for your algorithm (in case of "static" (not sequential data) packages like e.g. h20 in R or Scikit-learn in Python may do a great job) and in neural network case - normalize your data properly (e.g. subtract mean and divide by standard deviation every `x` column of your data).
2. Your dataset might be inconsistent. If e.g. your data has not a property that there exists a functional dependency between `x` and `y` (what means that `y = f(x)` for some `f`) then what is learnt during a training session is a probability that given `x` - your example belong to some specified class. This inconsistency might seriously harm your accuracy. What I advice you in this case is to try specify if that phenomenon occurs and then e.g. try to segmentate your data to solve the problem.
3. Your data set might be simply too small. Try to get more data in this case.

Comment: I have tried what you and Gaurav suggested but no luck. I just keep getting stuck at around 60% (I have a bigger dataset and less columns now). Could someone take a look at the data here http://www97.zippyshare.com/v/LqqORkx5/file.html If it is possible to get up to 80% it would be a great thing.